# How do I limit a Jquery effect to a certain div?

Tags: jquery

So I'm using the Firefly plugin on my personal site, and it obviously spanning its effects over the entire document.

How can I limit them to say, one `<li>` or a `<div>`?

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.firefly({images : ['/img/1.jpg', '/img/2.jpg'],total : 200});
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You are assuming that people know what that plugin is or does. Bad assumption

Comment: You're going to have to provide some of your HTML that you're targeting/trying to target, and be more specific. Are you only wanting to target the first instance of that item? The third instance? An instance depending on some other variable?

Comment: Choose correct selector for example $("li, div").firefly(...); effects on li or div elements.

Comment: It just adds some random particles that move in random patterns throughout the page. My question is, can I limit its effect to just one area rather than the entire document. Sorry.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper: Do you have a link to the plugin's documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "on" property

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.firefly({images : ['/img/1.jpg', '/img/2.jpg'],total : 200, on: '#header'});
    });
</script>
```

hope it helps

Comment: I've tried doing that prior and it seems to still span the entire document... which is odd.